# How to create a row with next ID number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to do a energy consumption calculator. I create a table with one row with ID "device_1". After clicking a button below table I want to create the same row but with ID "device_2" or more. Later, I would like to remove row after clicking "X" button. What should I do?

I can only make a simple duplicate row with the same ID. I have no idea how to fix this problem.

```
<tbody>
   <tr id="device_1">
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control name" value="" placeholder="Enter name"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control power" value="" placeholder="Enter power"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control time" value="" placeholder="Enter avg time of use"></td>
         <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" id="removeDevice" value="X"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just clone the original row, use `.attr` to set the id to the new one, and for deleting, find the closest `tr` and remove it (using event delegation so that it works on newly created rows):

```js
$(function() {
    var id = 1;
    var $row = $('#device_1');
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        id++;
        $('table').append($row.clone().attr('id', 'device_' + id));
    });
    $('table').on('click', '[type="button"]', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr id="device_1">
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control name" value="" placeholder="Enter name"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control power" value="" placeholder="Enter power"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control time" value="" placeholder="Enter avg time of use"></td>
         <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" id="removeDevice" value="X"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <button>+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your table has more rows at the beginning and the counting id should start from the last row and not 1 you can use the below (just updated dave above code ):

```
$(function() {
$('button').on('click', function() {
    //select the last tr row
    var row = $('table tr:last')
    //get the last row id number using split by _ and add +1
    var id = parseInt(row.attr('id').split('_')[1]) + 1;
    $('table').append(row.clone().attr('id', 'device_' + id));
});
$('table').on('click', '[type="button"]', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}); });
```

Comment: I can remove but I can't add. I have na error: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: have you changed the id pattern name? Please take a look here how this works (https://codepen.io/alexciu/pen/JVaGNR)